# HTMLEditor's content not see <br/>

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using an editor control of ajaxcontroltoolkit.

```
<cc1:Editor ID="EditNews" runat="server" NoUnicode="true"/>
```

My problem is that when I try to get the content of Editor by:

```
Literal1.Text = EditNews.Content;
```

if in the editor there are breakLine for example "If I write"

```
Text Text

Text



Text
```

In Literal I get:

```
Text Text
Text
Text
```

Whitout breakLine.

I don't know if this problem depends by an attribute that I haven't set in Editor or I have to control this "
" in Code Behind.

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried `<br />`(i.e. <br[space]/>) instead of `<br/>`.

Comment: Sorry, but I am expressed bad. I get this problem in the editor mode and not in html mode. So when I insert normal text, how I am doing in this time while I am answering you, when I press ENTER on the keyboard to do a breakline in effect, it doesnt' see this command and non interprets it

Answer (score 0):

I believe to understand the problem.
In effect is not a problem,but if you use the alignment (center,right, or left) and then directly you try to do breakline it doesn't work because in html it generate:

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px"></p>
```

If you don't use alignment and try to do breakline then it generate in html

```
<br/>
```

and so work correctly!

Now, I have another problem with my editor, in fact If I try to write very hard text, my editor cut text!

Answer (score 0):

If you want WYSWYG editor then just use FCK/CK Editor, those are really best ones.